# Is this even possible

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Is this possible?
[image: deseptively hard math problem]

**please provide a step by step explanation**

Comment: Please share the *Mathematica* code that you've tried so far.  And you might want to try Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Yes.
Steps: 1) Y, 2) E, 3) S.

In other news, perhaps you meant to ask for your homework answers on https://math.stackexchange.com/ ? This stack is for the software *Mathematica*...

Answer (score 1):

> please provide a step by step explanation

```
WolframAlpha["Integrate[Sqrt[Tan[x]],x]", 
 PodStates -> {"Step-by-step solution"}]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Another option is

```
<<Rubi`
Steps[Int[Sqrt[Tan[x]], x]]
```